# Hibernate SessionFactory vs Service Registry

Tags: hibernate, upgrade, sessionfactory

**Prior to Hibernate 4**

The way of implementation of session connection is only with SessionFactory.

**Example:**

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
Configuration cfg=cfg.configure(“mysql.cfg.xml”);
SessionFactory sf=cfg1.buildSessionFactory();
```

**Hibernate 4.0,4.1,4.2**

It changes with the concept of ServiceRegistry and the way of implementation is with ServiceRegistry & SessionFactory.

**Example:**

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
 configuration.configure();

 serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
 sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
 return sessionFactory;
```

**Hibernate 4.3**

ServiceRegistryBuilder() also deprecated and replaced with StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().

**Example:**

```
serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

**My questions are:**

1. What is the difference b/w SessionFactory & ServiceRegistry ?
2. Why Concept of ServiceRegistry is required ?
3. What is the advantage of introduce ServiceRegistry over SessionFactory ?
4. What is the difference b/w ServiceRegistryBuilder() & StandardServiceRegistryBuilder() ?

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2578 check this

Comment: I'm amazed why a question this important hasn't been answered yet, not even marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the SessionFactory object in two ways

first:

```
ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties()).build();

SessionFactory factory = con.buildSessionFactory(sr);
```

second:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

both of them use StandardServiceRegistry, but second one is shorter and use StandardServiceRegistry in the configure() method and you don't see it in your code